# Python - How to generate a Gaussian Random Vector using Scipy.Stats.Multivariate_Normal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I want to do the same thing as

```
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (n, 1))
```

where mean is a vector with length n and cov is a square nxn matrix, but with scipy.stats.multivariate_normal instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sample from a distribution in `scipy.stats` use the `.rvs` method.

Example:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> 
>>> n = 3
>>> mn = np.random.random(n)
>>> cov = np.random.random((2*n, n)) - 0.5
>>> cov = cov.T@cov
>>> 
>>> frzn = stats.multivariate_normal(mn, cov)
>>> frzn
<scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_frozen object at 0x7f156ea782b0>
>>> frzn.rvs(n)
array([[ 1.38391348,  0.65518546, -0.79541539],
       [ 0.36422157, -0.49308578,  0.94995824],
       [-0.73152442, -0.06003768, -0.28373662]])
```